# jQuery cycle plugin paging + CSS3PIE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cycle, css3pie

I am using the jQuery cycle plugin for a slideshow of images. With rounded bullets as pagers (because it's all the rage now so it seems). This worked perfectly in the 'modern' browsers except for IE. It is messing up the activePagerClass on the pagers.

Because IE can't do border-radius, I use the CSS3PIE behavior.

Comment: You should rewrite this. Make the question part a question, and add your own answer with the solution.

Comment: ok I will, in 7 hours, cause i can't answer my own questions yet so it seems...

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager,currSlide,clsName){
    $(pager).each(function(){
        $(this).children().removeClass(clsName).eq(currSlide).addClass(clsName);
     });
);
```

in the jQuery source code to

```
$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager,currSlide,clsName){
    $(pager).each(function(){
        $('a',this).removeClass(clsName).eq(currSlide).addClass(clsName);
    });
);
```

fixed it.

So it seems there is an issue with the children() function and the use of CSS3PIE. I'm not a fan of the behavior property and I would rather not use it, but the client wants rounded bullets in IE...

So I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: The way that CSS3Pie works is by modifying the dom and adding `<css3-container>` elements as siblings to any elements previously added. So, it's likely that the DOM traversal got messed up by these new elements. Therefore, restricting to  only anchors (`$('a',this)`) is a reasonable fix.