# CSS3Pie in JCarousel

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jcarousel, css3pie

I noticed the following strange behaviour when applying CSS3PIE to the Typo3 extension [jcarousel](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/imagecarousel:)

(which basically uses jquery jcarousel plugin).

When I am loading the page in IE 7 or IE 8 I do not see the images in JCarousel having rounded borders (want to apply border-radius on them) but when I go to the IE developer toolbar and change there any CSS property by unchecking it the images get the rounded borders.

My question now is: 
How can I get the images to have rounded borders directly when loading the page?

I already looked at [jQuery cycle plugin paging + CSS3PIE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499258/jquery-cycle-plugin-paging-css3pie) but I do not know where to search for a similar place in one of the included js-Files the extension uses.

Moreover I think on the fact that it works once a CSS property is unchecked in IE developper toolbar. Does anyone know how the IE works or can get a conclusion from this fact that might help me.

I appreciate any of your answers and am looking forward to it :)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I nearly found the answer:

As it renders again the CSS when unchecking some property in IE Developer toolbar I have to trigger this CSS rendering by
changing some CSS via JQuery, for example

```
$('.something').addClass('someClass').
```

Putting such a call in the last line
of the initCallback function of the Typo3 JCarousel extension (in jcarousel-1.2.1.min.js) yield to the fact that it works when I call the page a second time. Task left is too find the way to make the browser showing the rounded corners when calling the browser the first time.

By the way:
You should not rely on IE developer toolbar with its browser modus when some JS-CSS-Changing comes with it (especially with CSS3Pie). For this use better IE Tester as I there saw the rounded corners when browser calling a second time while in IE Dev Toolbar not.
Another hot tip which I got today:
 http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools